# AttributeError: module 'functools' has no attribute 'wraps'

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, python-import, importerror

I am trying to test 3rd party code with Anaconda 4.2 / Python 3.5 When I execute tests I get following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyspark/sql/tests.py", line 25, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 364, in <module>
    import signal
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/signal.py", line 3, in <module>
    from functools import wraps as _wraps
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 22, in <module>
    from types import MappingProxyType
  File "/home/user/Spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 22, in <module>
    import calendar
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/calendar.py", line 10, in <module>
    import locale as _locale
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/locale.py", line 108, in <module>
    @functools.wraps(_localeconv)
AttributeError: module 'functools' has no attribute 'wraps'
```

Normally I would assume some module is shadowing built-in modules but as far as I can tell this is not the issue:

- I logged module path (`functools.__file__`) from the tests and it yields expected path. Also there is nothing strange in the path I get in the exception.
- To exclude possible module corruption I tested completely new Anaconda installation.
- When I execute tests, with the same configuration and path, from IPython shell (`%run pyspark/sql/tests.py`) problem disappears.
- `functools.wraps` can be imported in the shell started in the same directory and with the same configuration.
- When I replace Python 3 environment with Python 2 environment problem disappears.
- Problem cannot be reproduced with environment create using `virtualenv`.

With different version of the same project I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyspark/sql/tests.py", line 25, in <module>
    import pydoc
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/pydoc.py", line 55, in <module>
    import importlib._bootstrap
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "/home/user/Spark/spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 22, in <module>
    import calendar
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/calendar.py", line 10, in <module>
    import locale as _locale
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/locale.py", line 19, in <module>
    import functools
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 22, in <module>
    from types import MappingProxyType
ImportError: cannot import name 'MappingProxyType'
```

Is there something obvious I missed here?

**Edit**:

Dockerfile which can be used to reproduce the problem:

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget bzip2
RUN wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN bash Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /anaconda3
RUN wget ftp://ftp.piotrkosoft.net/pub/mirrors/ftp.apache.org/spark/spark-2.1.0/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
RUN tar xf spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
ENV PATH /anaconda3/bin:$PATH
ENV SPARK_HOME /spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7
ENV PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip:$SPARK_HOME/python
WORKDIR /spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7
RUN python python/pyspark/sql/tests.py
```

Comment: What is your `functools.__file__`? You said you logged it (I hope you logged it where the exception happens, right?), what does it show when you run it normally and what does it show when you run it from the IPython shell?

Comment: @MSeifert It shows the same path both times, and it is the one I see in tracebacks (`/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/functools.py`).

Comment: just to exclude a common mistake: did you try to call the failing command from a different directory?

Comment: @MSeifert I did to no avail and I am fairly confident I don't have loose `functools` module on the path :/ I guess I must have mess up something big time. The second exception troubles me even more to be honest, since it suggests some wider problem (Python 2 modules on the path) Thing is code works just fine otherwise.

Comment: Now that you mention it: your folders seem weird. You have `anaconda/lib/pythonx.x/functools.py` while on my computer it's `anaconda/lib/functools.py` (without the python). Is it possible that you **manually** installed a python distribution into your anaconda distribution instead of using your anaconda python?

Comment: @MSeifert I am pretty sure I've been able to reduce this problem to a [mcve] but it made me even more confused. Maybe you'll be able to make some sense out of it. Last but not least - thank you so much for your questions and time.

Comment: Oh, that seems pretty bad, I'm almost certain you shouldn't install `spark` like that in combination with `conda`. Have you checked for any instructions how that should be done? I found two promising looking [blog post](https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/using-anaconda-pyspark-distributed-language-processing-hadoop-cluster) (and [2](https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/conda-spark)) on that subject but I never used hadoop or spark before so I can't comment on that score.

Comment: @MSeifert Oh, I know. Using root account is bad enough :) I just try to reduce the problem to something that is not dependent on my own environment. I honestly cannot figure out what is going on here, and how this exception even occurs (is it Anaconda, PySpark, or some combination of these two).

Comment: No I meant because the `tar.gz` you download contains it's own python distribution as well. But that's **far beyond my knowledge**. I hope someone else will have some more valuable input. Btw: You could consider adding the "python" tag as well, normally that's a bit more frequently visited.

Comment: It doesn't. It only contains a [package in which is placed in python directory](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/python). As far as I can tell there is nothing that could really result in this behavior. Not to  mention it doesn't happen if use virtualenv, not Anaconda. Thanks for the tag hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this is happening because, the `functools` module of `python3` has the following import: `from types import MappingProxyType` and, instead of picking up this module from `${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/python3.5/types.py`, it tries to import the module from inside the sql directory: `${SPARK_HOME}/python/pyspark/sql/types.py` . The `functools` module of `python2` does not have this import and hence does not throw the error.

A workaround to this, is to somehow import the *required* `types` module first and then invoke the script. As a proof of concept:

```
(root) ~/condaexpts$ PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip:$SPARK_HOME/python python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import types
>>> import os
>>> sqltests=os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] + '/python/pyspark/sql/tests.py'
>>> exec(open(sqltests).read())
.....Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/01/30 05:59:43 WARN SparkContext: Support for Java 7 is deprecated as of Spark 2.0.0
17/01/30 05:59:44 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 128 tests in 372.565s
```

Also note that there is nothing special about `conda`. One can see the same thing in a normal virtualenv (with python3):

```
~/condaexpts$ virtualenv -p python3 venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in venv/bin/python3
Also creating executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.

~/condaexpts$ source venv/bin/activate

(venv)~/condaexpts$ python --version
Python 3.4.3

(venv)~/condaexpts$ python $WORKDIR/python/pyspark/sql/tests.py                                                                                                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/condaexpts/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/tests.py", line 26, in <module>
    import pydoc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/pydoc.py", line 59, in <module>
    import importlib._bootstrap
  File "/home/ubuntu/condaexpts/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    import types
  File "/home/ubuntu/condaexpts/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 22, in <module>
    import calendar
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/calendar.py", line 10, in <module>
    import locale as _locale
  File "/home/ubuntu/condaexpts/venv/lib/python3.4/locale.py", line 20, in <module>
    import functools
  File "/home/ubuntu/condaexpts/venv/lib/python3.4/functools.py", line 22, in <module>
    from types import MappingProxyType
ImportError: cannot import name 'MappingProxyType'
```

Comment: This is plausible explanation (I'll try to verify this and get back to you, cannot upvote I am afraid) but what troubles me is that I cannot reproduce the problem with standard virtual environment.  Do you have any insights what is the difference compared to Anaconda that could result in this behavior? And is it a bug or a feature? :)

Comment: @user7487351 I get the same error in a virtualenv with python3

Comment: Huh, now I can upvote. But this is weird... And you get the second one, not `AttributeError: module 'functools' has no attribute 'wraps'` :/

Comment: And you're right. Renaming `types` module indeed resolves the problem.  Nice catch and thanks a bunch.